# Unauthorised transfers to developer's account in bank transaction software

Tags: banks, software

Our organization has software for transactions. The person who designed this software illegally designed it in such a way that when any transaction is performed 0.5 percent of the transaction goes into his account.

Is there any solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: Use different software, and have the person arrested.

Comment: Please use proper tagging. This question has nothing to do with privacy.

Comment: This question is confusing. What problem do you want to be solved? The obvious response is to do what John Wu said: stop using the software and report the crime.

Comment: Is it possible that you meant to ask "how to detect this sort of problem" rather than how to resolve it after it has been discovered?

Comment: This is the plot to more than one movie, eg Superman, Office Space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...stop using the software until it can be vetted, and the malicious code removed. Your company should have a secure coding/audit process and be doing reviews to prevent this sort of thing. If it is indeed processing payments or performing some sort of transactions, it is pretty concerning that this happened and no one knows how to fix it. You may want to bring in an outside security firm who specializes in this sort of thing.  Also, ask the employee if he enjoyed Office Space.

Comment: As I read through the question again I realize you may have purchased this as a 3rd party solution. If that's the case, ditch the software, and consider hiring outside security help to ensure your network hasn't been breached as a result of installing and running this software. Also as stated above, report the person to the correct authorities in your country.